# Docker API: cpu_stats vs percpu_stats

Tags: docker

What is the difference between 
cpu_stats and percpu_stats when using Docker remote API:

The request is :

```
GET /containers/(id or name)/stats
```

(A part of) The response is:

```
 "cpu_stats" : {
    "cpu_usage" : {
       "percpu_usage" : [
          8646879,
          24472255,
          36438778,
          30657443
       ],
       "usage_in_usermode" : 50000000,
       "total_usage" : 100215355,
       "usage_in_kernelmode" : 30000000
    },
    "system_cpu_usage" : 739306590000000,
    "throttling_data" : {"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}
 },
 "precpu_stats" : {
    "cpu_usage" : {
       "percpu_usage" : [
          8646879,
          24350896,
          36438778,
          30657443
       ],
       "usage_in_usermode" : 50000000,
       "total_usage" : 100093996,
       "usage_in_kernelmode" : 30000000
    },
    "system_cpu_usage" : 9492140000000,
    "throttling_data" : {"periods":0,"throttled_periods":0,"throttled_time":0}
 }
```

Example taken from Docker docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.24/#get-container-stats-based-on-resource-usage

When testing with a sample container, values are almost the same.

Example of an output:

```
#Cpu stas
{u'cpu_usage': {u'usage_in_usermode': 0, u'total_usage': 36569630, u'percpu_usage': [8618616, 3086454, 16466404, 8398156], u'usage_in_kernelmode': 20000000}, u'system_cpu_usage': 339324470000000, u'throttling_data': {u'throttled_time': 0, u'periods': 0, u'throttled_periods': 0}}

#Per cup stats
{u'cpu_usage': {u'usage_in_usermode': 0, u'total_usage': 36569630, u'percpu_usage': [8618616, 3086454, 16466404, 8398156], u'usage_in_kernelmode': 20000000}, u'system_cpu_usage': 339320550000000, u'throttling_data': {u'throttled_time': 0, u'periods': 0, u'throttled_periods': 0}}
```

I tried also to compare specific metrics in the two case for 4 containers:

```
#First container
359727340000000 #CPU Stats
359723390000000 #Per CPU Stats

#2
359735220000000
359731290000000

#3
359743100000000
359739170000000

#4
359750940000000
359747000000000
```

The values above are almost same (some differences but not huge - may be because there are some ms between each request.)

In the official documentation:

> The precpu_stats is the cpu statistic of last read, which is used for
>   calculating the cpu usage percent. It is not the exact copy of the
>   “cpu_stats” field.

Not very clear for me.
Anyone could explain better ?